# I can't make my kali linux resolution 1280x1024

Tags: linux, resolution, kali-linux

First,I use KaliLinux Distrubtion The screen stuck in 1024x768

I tried xrandr But it didn't work First, I write in terminal cvt 1280 1024 60 
The Output is : "1280x1024_60.00" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
Then , I write xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync 
Next, xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.00 Then, xrandr --output --mode 1280x1024_60.00 It doesn't work Then i tries the command : xrandr --output --mode 1280x1024_60.00 many times then it works But The screen is divided into other similar screens I can't do anything The mouse can move But Nothing work I tries to click on anything but nothing happen Please HELP !!!

Comment: If you don't know exactly what drivers you may need to intall then Kali is not for you.

Comment: Kali is not what you could call user friendly, so it's recommended to start with a more user-friendly distro, such as Ubuntu http://ubuntu.com

Comment: GabrielaGarcia
I don't know exactly what drivers i need to *install
Why do you say "Kali is not for you"
How can i know exactly what drivers i need to install ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a common Problem in virtual machines, with too less VRam.
 Do you run one???
If not, worked other OS and when they worked, I would try to reinstall and just look its ok. The installation does not take long. I think i heared about somethink simular at a multiboot system

Comment: My friend
I already dual boot kali linux and windows
i don't use kali linux as virtual machine
i use it as main system